# How to get address of a pointer in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c

How to get address of a pointer in **c/c++**?

Eg: I have below code.

```
int a =10;
int *p = &a;
```

So how do I get address of pointer `p`?
Now I want to print address of p, what should I do?

print("%s",???) what I pass to ???.

Comment: you should not use "%s" to print an integer-like value.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

To get the address of p do:

```
int **pp = &p;
```

and you can go on:

```
int ***ppp = &pp;
int ****pppp = &ppp;
...
```

or, only in C++11, you can do:

```
auto pp = std::addressof(p);
```

To print the address in C, most compilers support `%p`, so you can simply do:

```
printf("addr: %p", pp);
```

otherwise you need to cast it (assuming a 32 bit platform)

```
printf("addr: 0x%u", (unsigned)pp);
```

In C++ you can do:

```
cout << "addr: " << pp;
```

Comment: I tried cout << &p and got an error. How come it's not as simple as that?

Comment: And, howto restore the pointer address to var? by example `int *pp = getponterexample(address)` ?

Comment: @ILike I tried it, its working fine. The statements `cout << &p;` and `cout << pp;` print the same address.

Answer (score 22):

```
int a = 10;
```

To get the address of a, you do: `&a` (address of `a`) which returns an `int*` (pointer to int)

```
int *p = &a;
```

Then you store the address of a in `p` which is of type `int*`.

Finally, if you do `&p` you get the address of `p` which is of type `int**`, i.e. pointer to pointer to int:

```
int** p_ptr = &p;
```

just seen your edit:

to print out the pointer's address, you either need to convert it:

```
printf("address of pointer is: 0x%0X\n", (unsigned)&p);
printf("address of pointer to pointer is: 0x%0X\n", (unsigned)&p_ptr);
```

or if your printf supports it, use the `%p`:

```
printf("address of pointer is: %p\n", p);
printf("address of pointer to pointer is: %p\n", p_ptr);
```

Answer (score 7):

`&a` gives address of `a` - `&p` gives address of `p`.

```
int * * p_to_p = &p;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use %p in C

In C:

```
printf("%p",p)
```

In C++:

```
cout<<"Address of pointer p is: "<<p
```

Answer (score 2):

Having this C source:

```
int a = 10;
int * ptr = &a;
```

Use this

```
printf("The address of ptr is %p\n", (void *) &ptr);
```

to print the address of `ptr`.

Please note that the conversion specifier `p` is the only conversion specifier to print a pointer's value **and** it is defined to be used with `void*` typed pointers only.

From [`man printf`:](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)

> **p**
>
> The *void ** pointer argument is printed in hexadecimal (as if
>                 by %**#x** or %**#lx**).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `%p` formatter. It's always best practice cast your pointer `void*` before printing.

The C standard says:

> The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner.

Here's how you do it:

```
printf("%p", (void*)p);
```

Comment: this seems to be wrong there is a & missing in front of the p

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

in C

```
int a =10;
int *p = &a;     
int **pp = &p;
printf("%u",&p);
```

in C++

```
cout<<p;
```

Comment: In the above example, `cout<<p;` actually prints the address to the object being _pointed to_, not the address of the pointer itself. The pointer's address can be accessed via `&p`.

Answer (score 1):

In **C++** you can do:

```
// Declaration and assign variable a
int a = 7;
// Declaration pointer b
int* b;
// Assign address of variable a to pointer b
b = &a;

// Declaration pointer c
int** c;
// Assign address of pointer b to pointer c
c = &b;

std::cout << "a: " << a << "\n";       // Print value of variable a
std::cout << "&a: " << &a << "\n";     // Print address of variable a

std::cout << "" << "" << "\n";

std::cout << "b: " << b << "\n";       // Print address of variable a
std::cout << "*b: " << *b << "\n";     // Print value of variable a
std::cout << "&b: " << &b << "\n";     // Print address of pointer b

std::cout << "" << "" << "\n";

std::cout << "c: " << c << "\n";       // Print address of pointer b
std::cout << "**c: " << **c << "\n";   // Print value of variable a
std::cout << "*c: " << *c << "\n";     // Print address of variable a
std::cout << "&c: " << &c << "\n";     // Print address of pointer c
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should understand the pointer is not complex. A pointer is showing the address of the variable.

Example:

```c
int a = 10;
int *p = &a;  // This means giving a pointer of variable "a" to int pointer variable "p"
```

And, you should understand "Pointer is an address" and "address is numerical value". So, you can get the address of variable as Integer.

```c
int a = 10;
unsigned long address = (unsigned long)&a;

// comparison
printf("%p\n", &a);
printf("%ld\n", address);
```

output is below

```
0x7fff1216619c
7fff1216619c
```

Note:

If you use a 64-bit computer, you can't get pointer by the way below.

```c
int a = 10;
unsigned int address = (unsigned int)&a;
```

Because pointer is 8 bytes (64 bit) on a 64-bit machine, but int is 4 bytes. So, you can't give an 8-byte memory address to 4 bytes variable.

You have to use `long long` or `long` to get an address of the variable.

- `long long` is always 8 bytes.
- `long` is 4 bytes when code was compiled for a 32-bit machine.
- `long` is 8 bytes when code was compiled for a 64-bit machine.

Therefore, you should use `long` to receive a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to compile these codes from a Linux terminal, you might get an error saying

> expects argument type int

Its because, when you try to get the memory address by `printf`, you cannot specify it as `%d` as its shown in the video.
Instead of that try to put `%p`.

Example:

```
// this might works fine since the out put is an integer as its expected.
printf("%d\n", *p); 

// but to get the address:
printf("%p\n", p);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Building off the above answers, if you had the pointer as a private variable, then you can make a getter function like so:**

```
private int* p;

public int** GetP() { return &p; }
```

**Then when you use it you create a pointer to your class that contains it:**

```
DummyClass* p_dummyClass = new DummyClass;
```

**And then in your use case scenario:**

```
p_dummyClass -> GetP();
```

(don't forget to deallocate)

Answer (score -1):

```
static inline unsigned long get_address(void *input){
    unsigned long ret;
    __asm__(
      ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
      "mov rax, %1;"
      "mov %0, rax;"
      ".att_syntax;"
      : "=r"(ret)
      : "r"(input));
      return ret;
}
```